# jquery validator - add Rule with Message, Error Class to dynamically created text box

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, jquery-validate

I am using MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js for form validation and it's working great except that I have some dynamic ajax content in my forms that I want to add validation to and I am struggling to work out how to do it.

If for example if I have dynamically create text input called ImageDescription how do I then add a simple regex test e.g. ^[^<>]$, an error message saying "Cannot contain HTML" and also specify the error div that the message should display in...

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO post : [jquery validate on elements not yet created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672155/jquery-validate-on-elements-not-yet-created)